# adding subClass object to List<? extends Subclass> create error

Tags: java, generics, gson

I have a problem with generic List. I spent few hours searching for a solution and the best I could do is below. Here is my code:

```
private <T extends SonarContainPaging> T getSonarObjectFromPage(String url, Map<String, Object> uriVariables, Class<T> klass, int page) {
    String json = //create the Json

    return objectMappingFromJson(json, klass);
}

private <T extends SonarContainPaging> void getSonarListContainingPaging(String url, Map<String, Object> uriVariables, Class<T> klass, List<T> list) {
    int page = 1;

    SonarContainPaging sonarObject = getSonarObjectFromPage(url, uriVariables, klass, page);
    page++;

    list.add(sonarObject);
    while (sonarObject.canContinueLooping(page)) {
        sonarObject = getSonarObjectFromPage(url, uriVariables, klass, page);
        page++;

        list.add(sonarObject);
    }
}
```

the method `objectMappingFromJson` call `gson.fromJson(json, classOfObject);`
and return a generic object `T`.

When I tried to add the object `sonarObject` in the list, I get the following error:

> The method add(T) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (SonarContainPaging)

I think casting the `sonarObject` to the type `(T)` would solve the problem. But it is strange. 
I declared that `<T extends SonarContainPaging>`, I don't get why there is this error.

---

**EDIT:**
Like I was told by @Andy Turner, I changed the method to:

```
private <T extends SonarContainPaging> void getSonarListContainingPaging(String url, Map<String, Object> uriVariables, Class<T> klass,
                                                                         List<? super SonarContainPaging> list);
```

Which solve the problem of adding an object in the list.
But it created an another one:

```
List<SonarComponentTree> list = new ArrayList<SonarComponentTree>();
getSonarListContainingPaging(urlBuilder.toString(), uriVariables, SonarComponentTree.class, list);
```

I cannot call the method `getSonarListContainingPaging` with a List of `SonarComponentTree`.

> `SonarComponentTree` implements `SonarContainPaging`.

```
The method getSonarListContainingPaging(String, Map<String,Object>, Class<T>, List<? super SonarContainPaging>)
in the type SonarRestApiServiceImpl is not applicable for the arguments
(String, Map<String,Object>, Class<SonarComponentTree>, List<SonarComponentTree>)
```

If I change back the list parameter to `List<? extends SonarContainPaging> list` the issue is resolved, but I am back where I was at the beginning.
I can't add an another object in the list.

I read @Michael Myers solution in the link given by @Andy Turner and it seems that I should use neither `extends` nor `super`, actually, it may be a conception error.

---

**Final Edit:**

The first answer actually works, you just need to cast the object to `(T)sonarObject`.
You just need to bear the warning.

Comment: `<T extends SonarContainPaging>`, but that can be *anything* that extends `SonarContainPaging`, not necessarily `SonarContainPaging` itself. If you want to add a `SonarContainPaging` to `list`, it needs to be `List<SonarContainPaging>` or `List<? super SonarContainPaging>`.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to change method with something else. ^^
Should I mark the question as answered?

Comment: There is no mechanism for you to mark the question answered.